# Work-around for auto-playing youtube videos on mobile

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm using the youtube player API to programatically play a collection of youtube videos back to back.

1. I load an array with 10 youtube_ids.
2. User clicks play on the youtube-player iframe
3. First video plays
4. User needs to click on second video in order for it to play

I understand Youtube does not allow auto-play on mobile because of potential data issues. That's understandable for the first video in the playlist.

But I'm wondering if there's some sort of workaround to get the subsequent videos to play in this scenario because the user is actually taking an action to cause the first video to play. e.g. Can I put an event listener on their first click that delays the "playVideo()" function for subsequent videos?

Any other workaround ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use a single iframe and the [loadVideoById](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById) function to load subsequent videos into the same frame, you can manage your videos entirely via the API commands after the user's initial play.

Comment: Thank you - I'm looking into this right now and if it works, it's exactly what I'm looking for.